# How to send all calls to voicemail except whitelist contacts in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app where I need to send all calls automatically to voicemail except a few whitelist contacts whose IDs I am storing in a different table of my app. Can some one suggest me a right approach of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

here is a code i already wore, where i can select the contacts in a list in order to direct all calls from those contacts directly to the mailbox, or not to the mailbox.

```
StringBuilder mailboxIds = new StringBuilder(""); // a stringbuilder that collects the id of the checked contacts in the list
    int visibleItemCount = contactAdapter.getCount(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItemCount; i++) { // iterating the visible and checked contacts of the list
        ContactItem contactItem = contactAdapter.getItem(i);
        if (contactItem.isChecked()) {
            mailboxIds.append(contactItem.getId() + ","); // creating a coma-seperated string with the ideas for the later query
        }
    }

    mailboxIds.replace(mailboxIds.length() - 1, mailboxIds.length(), ""); // removing the last coma from the list
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    if(toMailbox){ // if all selected contacts should go to the mailbox
        contentValues.put(Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL, 1);
    }else{ // if all selected contacts should not go to the mailbox
        contentValues.put(Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL, 0);
    }
    contentResolver.update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, BaseColumns._ID + " IN (" + mailboxIds + ")", null); // updating all contacs of the selected ids
```

you can collect the ids of the whitelist in this stringbuffer, set the contentValues to contentValues.put(Contacts.SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL, 1) and change my code to NOT IN (